# How to update data from android studio into mysql?

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update table member inside mysql. The update happened after user login the app, and they need to update their info on the edit activity. However, when I tried to run the app, the error displayed "Username not set". I am new into using mysql with android studio, thus this problem may occurred due to my own silly mistakes.

edit.java:

```
package com.example.psscmmanagementsystem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class edit extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    float x1,x2,y1,y2;
    String[] datagender = {"Female", "Male"};
    String[] datanationality = {"Malaysian", "Non-Malaysian"};
    Spinner etgender, etnationality;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private OkHttpClient client;
    private Response response;
    private RequestBody requestBody;
    Request request;
    TextView name, ic, matric;


    private EditText etAddress, etPostcode, etState, etPhone, etRace;
    private Button msave;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        etgender = findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);
        etnationality = findViewById(R.id.spinner_nationality);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGender = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datagender);
        adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        etgender.setAdapter(adapterGender);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNationality = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datanationality);
        adapterNationality.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        etnationality.setAdapter(adapterNationality);

        name = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        ic = findViewById(R.id.etIC);
        matric = findViewById(R.id.etMatric);
        etAddress = findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
        etPostcode = findViewById(R.id.etPostcode);
        etState = findViewById(R.id.etState);
        etPhone = findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        etRace = findViewById(R.id.etRace);
        etnationality = findViewById(R.id.spinner_nationality);
        etgender = findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);
        msave = findViewById(R.id.msave);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        msave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.show();
                saveDataVolley();
            }
        });



    }
    // Method to get and display data
    private void getDataFromDatabase() {
        // Retrieve username from SharedPreferences
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        String ic = sessionManager.getUsername();
        Log.d("edit", "Username retrieved from SessionManager: " + ic);

        // Use Volley to make a request to your PHP script
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Db_Contract.urlgetdata, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    // Convert the response to a JSON object
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                    // Get the user data from the JSON object
                    String username = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                    String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                    String matric = jsonResponse.getString("matric");

                    // Set the TextViews with the retrieved data
                    ic.setText(username);
                    name.setText(name);
                    matric.setText(matric);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error parsing JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Pass the username to the PHP script
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", ic);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    public void saveDataVolley(){
        // Retrieve username from SharedPreferences
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        String ic = sessionManager.getUsername();

        String Address = etAddress.getText().toString().trim();
        String Postcode = etPostcode.getText().toString().trim();
        String State = etState.getText().toString().trim();
        String Phone = etPhone.getText().toString().trim();
        String Race = etRace.getText().toString().trim();
        String Nationality = etnationality.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String Gender = etgender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();


        if(!(Address.isEmpty()) || (Postcode.isEmpty()) || (State.isEmpty()) || (Phone.isEmpty())|| (Race.isEmpty())|| (Nationality.isEmpty())|| (Gender.isEmpty())){

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Db_Contract.urlgetdata, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("edit", "response : " + response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            {
                @Override
                //untuk simpan data dalam mysql guna php12345
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    HashMap<String, String> updateParams = new HashMap<>();

                    updateParams.put("address", Address);
                    updateParams.put("postcode", Postcode);
                    updateParams.put("state", State);
                    updateParams.put("phone", Phone);
                    updateParams.put("race", Race);
                    updateParams.put("nationality", Nationality);
                    updateParams.put("gender", Gender);

                    return updateParams;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all required data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent){
        switch (touchEvent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1=touchEvent.getX();
                y1=touchEvent.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2=touchEvent.getX();
                y2=touchEvent.getY();
                if(x1>x2){ //swipe right
                    Intent i = new Intent(edit.this, beneficiary.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(x1<x2){
                    Intent i = new Intent (edit.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

activity_edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".edit">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registration Form"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:alpha="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="IC No."
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Matric No."
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/etIC"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/etMatric"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAddress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Postcode"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="State        "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPostcode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etState"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Phone. No"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Race          "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etPhone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etRace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Nationality"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_gender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </Spinner>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_nationality"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </Spinner>


            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/msave"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/smallbuttonbg"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

getdata.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include 'Constants.php';

$heroes = array();

// Check if the variable $username is set
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // Get the username from the POST request
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
        $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $race = $_POST['race'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $nationality = $_POST['nationality'];

    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        // Handle the case where you want to update user data

        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE member
                      SET address=?, postcode=?, state=?, phone=?, race=?, gender=?, nationality=?
                      WHERE username=?";
        $stmtUpdate = $conn->prepare($sqlUpdate);
        $stmtUpdate->bind_param('ssssssss', $address, $postcode, $state, $phone, $race, $gender, $nationality, $username);

        if ($stmtUpdate->execute()) {
            echo "Data updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Update failed: " . $stmtUpdate->error;
        }

        $stmtUpdate->close();
    } else {
        // Handle the case where you want to retrieve user data
        $sqlSelect = "SELECT username, matric, name, postcode, state, phone, race, nationality, gender, password FROM member WHERE username=?";
        $stmtSelect = $conn->prepare($sqlSelect);
        $stmtSelect->bind_param('s', $username);

        $stmtSelect->execute();

        $stmtSelect->bind_result($username, $matric, $name, $postcode, $state, $phone, $race, $nationality, $gender, $password);

        while ($stmtSelect->fetch()) {
            // Push fetched data into an array
            $temp = [
                'username' => $username,
                'matric' => $matric,
                'name' => $name,
                'postcode' => $postcode,
                'state' => $state,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'race' => $race,
                'nationality' => $nationality,
                'gender' => $gender,
                'password' => $password
            ];

            // Push the array inside the heroes array
            array_push($heroes, $temp);
        }

        // Display the data in JSON format
        echo json_encode($heroes);
        $stmtSelect->close();
    }

    $stmtSelect->close();
} else {
    echo "Username not set";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I am expecting the data input by user can be updated into the database table, and i can fetch data from database to be displayed under ic, name and matric textview. I do hope that at least, I can understand what is wrong with the code to make my fyp project at least runnable.

this could make me happy in tears if you guys can make it happen for me :'D

Comment: Phpmyadmin is a database frontend, so actually you want to get the data into the underlying database.